# Whats the Balanced chemical equation for heating sodium chloride and what type of a reaction is it?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

For my chemistry lab we had to heat sodium chloride and there was a colour change and a sizzling sound. Is it a decomposition or synthesis reaction, and what is the balanced chemical equation for it?

Comment: Doesn't sound like sodium chloride to me; salt is pretty thermally stable, although you could conceivably melt it with a blow torch (mp. is 801 degrees C).

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be that this was rather the dissociation of **Sodium Carbonate** or **Sodium Hydrogen Carbonate**.

The equations for the dissociation of **Sodium Carbonate** and **Sodium Hydrogen Carbonate**, respectively, are as follows:

> $$\ce{Na2CO3 -> Na2O + CO2}$$

$$\ce{and}$$

> $$\ce{2 NaHCO3 -> Na2O + H2O + 2 CO2}$$

Comment: a rather wild guess, i think